# How can I use non-trivial YYSTYPE in win bison

Tags: c++, compilation, bison, yacc

At first I use bison's LR parser and now because of some grammar hard to handle I decide to take a chance on bison's GLR parser.

Currently I define `YYSTYPE` to a non-trivial class `ParseNode`, however I found in bison's generated code

```
union yyGLRStackItem {
  yyGLRState yystate;
  yySemanticOption yyoption; // my YYSTYPE is located in the struct
};
```

my non-trivial class is wrapped in a `union`, so the whole code won't compile.

By seaching, I found [%define api.value.type](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Type-Generation.html) may help me.

But no matter how I tried, the output always shows

```
error: %define variable 'api.value.type' is not used
```

My win_bison version is win_bison 2.4.8/2.5.8. Maybe this version is not support bison 3.0? If so, what else can I do?

**EDIT**

Before I use bison's LR parser, and I used my `ParseNode`, though the stack can not grow automaticly, it actually WORKED before I switch to GLR parser.
I defined `ParseNode` like following:

```
struct ParseNode {
    FlexState fs; // all infomation I got from flex
    std::vector<ParseNode *> child;
    struct ParseNode * father;
    struct ParseAttr * attr = nullptr;
    void addchild(const ParseNode & n);
    ParseNode & get(int child_index);
    const ParseNode & get(int child_index) const;
    void setattr(ParseAttr * pa);
    std::string to_string() const { return fs.CurrentTerm.what; }

    ParseNode(const ParseNode &);
    ParseNode & operator= (const ParseNode &) ;
    ParseNode() = default;
    ParseNode(const FlexState & s, ParseNode * fa, ParseAttr * att = nullptr) : father(fa), attr(att), fs(s) {}
    ~ParseNode();
};
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is my implemetation of `ParseNode`

```
ParseNode::~ParseNode()
{
    delete attr;
    for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++)
    {
        delete child[i];
    }
}
ParseNode::ParseNode(const ParseNode & pn)
{ 
    this->fs = pn.fs;
    this->father = pn.father;
    this->attr = (pn.attr == nullptr ? nullptr: pn.attr->clone());
    for (int i = 0; i < pn.child.size(); i++)
    {
        if (pn.child[i] != nullptr) {
            this->addchild(pn.get(i));
        }
        else {
            this->addchildptr(nullptr);
        }
    }
}
ParseNode & ParseNode::operator= (const ParseNode & pn) {
    if (this == &pn) {
        return *this;
    }
    else {
        delete this->attr;
        for (int i = 0; i < child.size(); i++)
        {
            delete child[i];
        }
        this->child.clear();

        this->fs = pn.fs;
        this->father = pn.father;
        this->attr = (pn.attr == nullptr ? nullptr : pn.attr->clone());
        for (int i = 0; i < pn.child.size(); i++)
        {
            this->addchild(pn.get(i));
        }

        return *this;
    }
}
void ParseNode::addchildptr(ParseNode * ptrn, bool add_back) {
    if (ptrn != nullptr) {
        ptrn->father = this;
    }
    if (add_back) {
        this->child.push_back(ptrn);
    }
    else {
        this->child.insert(this->child.begin(), ptrn);
    }
}
void ParseNode::addchild(const ParseNode & n, bool add_back ) {
    this->addchildptr(new ParseNode(n), add_back);
}
```

I implement my `ParseNode` class by the RAII method, because the resource management will be handled automaticlly by the compiler. So I can write code like this:

```
/* more codes */
exp : exp '+' exp 
        {
            const ParseNode & exp1 = $1;
            const ParseNode & op = $2;
            const ParseNode & exp2 = $3;
            ParseNode newnode = gen_exp(exp1, op, exp2);
            newnode.addchild(exp1); // add a copy of left operand exp's ParseNode
            newnode.addchild(op); // op
            newnode.addchild(exp2); // add a copy of right operand exp's ParseNode
            $$ = newnode;
        }
    /* more codes */
```

After `gen_exp` function generates a `ParseNode`, There are many `gen_` functions, they all accept `const ParseNode &` and return `ParseNode`. I don't have to worry about the three `ParseNode` on the right side, because when it's deconstructor is called, all the pointer's he possess(not including `father`) will be deleted. The `father` pointer which like a `weak_ptr`, don't have parsing usage other than helping me debug. As soon as the bison part code is finished, `%start` rule will return a completed syntax tree.

If I change my `ParseNode` into `ParseNode *`, what changes do I have to make? I decide to delete `$1.pointer_to_parsenode` to `$n.pointer_to_parsenode` at the end of every rules. Is it enough to avoid memory leaks and more importantly, reading dirty values or cause access violations?

Comment: Don't use a non-trivial semantic type :) `api.value.type` won't help you (and it also is not implemented on older versions of `bison`.) Was it working before you switched to a GLR grammar, or did you add the semantic type at the same time as you switched. If it was working, how? Were you using the C++ API?

Comment: I don't see how that can "work". It can compile,   but unless there is something I'm not seeing, your `child` and `parent` pointers point at transient objects, presumably on the parse stack, whose slots will be reused leaving the pointers dangling. The usual approach is to put a *pointer* to a complex type like that onto the stack; the pointer is a trivial object so it doesn't get in your way, but it does leave you responsible for memory management (fortuntaly that is not too difficult.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the normal approach to using a non-trivial datatype like your `ParseNode` is to use pointers to such objects rather than the objects itself as your semantic type.

The parse stack is, as its name implies, a stack, and elements are pushed and popped from it as the parse proceeds. It is, therefore, dangerous to create a reference or pointer to an object on the stack, since later on that stack slot might be occupied by a completely different object. Your `ParseNode` object includes such pointers:

```
std::vector<ParseNode *> child;
struct ParseNode * father;
```

Without seeing the code you use to maintain these pointers, it is hard to be definite, but it seems unlikely that you make a copy of a ParseNode prior to adding it to the `child` vector, for example; if the address of the node you're inserting into this vector is a stack slot, then you will certainly invoke Undefined Behaviour at some point during the execution. (**Edit**: OK, I was wrong: the implementation actually does make a deep copy of the entire tree prior to adding it to the `child` vector, thereby making the parser execution time quadratic instead of linear in the input size.)

Most of this problem vanishes if you make the semantic type a `ParseNode*` instead of a `ParseNode`, although you have to implement a memory management strategy. (This is not a disadvantage, since the memory management strategy of allowing the objects to be deleted when they are popped from the stack does not work at all.) In simple applications which only build a syntax **tree**, the problem is not serious because you can walk the tree to delete the nodes when you are finished with the root. If the application may form a syntax forest, for example through Common Sub Expression (CSE) optimizations, then memory management becomes more difficult. (Although a sweeping garbage collector is not too difficult to code, my usual approach is to allocate all nodes in a `std::deque` or equivalent, and then not worry about deleting any node until the entire syntax graph is no longer needed, at which point it is sufficient to just delete the backing store.)

Once you change the semantic type to a pointer, the problem with using a non-trivial type vanishes as well, since a pointer is a trivial type, even if what it points at is not.

The end result is a massive simplification both in your parse node implementation and in your client code (which no longer needs to worry about only using references to nodes in order to avoid expensive copies), at the cost of using a `std::unique_ptr` for the final AST root.

Comment: I updated my question with my `ParseNode` implementation(code in EDIT1 is declaration) and why I want to design like this at first. For my specific situation, how can I implement your strategy?

Comment: @calvin: OK, you got me. If you are prepared to copy the entire world every time you want to form a new tree node, then you can use your structure. But I have to say that the strategy seems absurd to me; forming a tree out of an operation and two subtrees should be O(1), not O(n); doing it your way makes your parser at least quadratic in the input size. Furthermore, you are not freeing yourself from manual memory management; at best, you have only hidden the ugliness in your node implementation.

Comment: In fact adding move constructor to my class is on my schedule, I haven't do that yet because I'm now caring correctness not performance. I think it's meaningless to talk about manual memory management, since it's unavoidable in cpp. Neither do I think using this RAII or that raw pointer or else like shared_ptr is more or less ugly. I am not familiar with managing raw pointer, so I choose RAII, that's it. Now the problem is I can't compile my code because of bison's generated code use union, so your suggestion of using raw pointer makes a good solution.

Comment: But if I switched to raw pointer strategy, what should I do to my existing code, is my **EDIT 2** enough? Would you please specify on that? Thank you.

Comment: @calvin: Obviously we have radically different coding philosophies so I won't attempt to impose mine any more. Yes, if you are content to always do a deep copy, then it is sufficient to delete the old value after the copy has been made.

Comment: Yes, it seems if I change my existing code to raw pointer, it'll involve a lot of code changes from copy semantic to move semantic, or the whole program will still suffer from high copy cost. I think you are right and I should rewrite my code according to your suggestions, though it seems to involve some other problems given my existing code. However, it's another question. Thank you for your patience

Comment: It is possible to set a fixed size stack, and your own YYSTYPE as a struct instead of a union. Info about setting YYINITDEPTH here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861945/how-to-increase-stack-size-in-bison-and-solve-memory-exhausted